# html text turning into ad out of no reason

Tags: html

I've come across a really strange situation (to me at least) while writing some plain html code as follows:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
      Name :<br><br><input type="text" name="contact_name" maxlength="20"><br><br>
      E-mail address :<br><br><input type="text" name="contact_email" maxlength="25"><br><br>
      Message :<br><br>
      <textarea name="contact_text" rows="6" cols="30" maxlength="1000"></textarea><br><br><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Send" style="padding:5px">
</form>
```

When i run the page which contains this snippet, 'Message: ' text turns into a clickable ad altough i've not taken any ad to my site.Can you give a hint how i can prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a free web host then the ads are likely to be being inserted automatically; there's not really much you can do about that, short of coughing up the money for a proper host.

If you're viewing it locally and getting the ads you've probably got some adware installed on your machine.

There's certainly some external factor here; there's nothing in your code to do with the ads.

Comment: I suppose it's a internal pc issue, since i'm using a paid host service. Thanks for help.